# Double \setminus

Tags: spacing, symbols

I'd like to generate a command, `\dblsetminus`, that will print, in math mode, an operator similar to `\setminus`, but double. I've been able to approximate my desired operator with the following code:

```
\newcommand\dblsetminus{\setminus\hspace{-1ex}\setminus}
```

The problem with this is that the spacing following my version of `\dblsetminus` doesn't behave like the spacing following `\setminus`. For instance, in an expression like `A\dblsetminus B` the spacing after the operator is not the same as the spacing before the operator.

How can I get the surrounding spacing to behave like an operator's spacing should?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving left the second `\setminus` should not be done with `\hspace{-1ex}`, but with `\mspace`. The whole symbol should be made into a `\mathbin`.

```
\newcommand{\dblsetminus}{\mathbin{{\setminus}\mspace{-5mu}{\setminus}}}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\dblsetminus}{\mathbin{{\setminus}\mspace{-5mu}{\setminus}}}

\begin{document}

$A\dblsetminus B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the spacing to suit. Exercise: why `{\setminus}`?

Comment: Right: why `{\setminus}`?

Comment: @GuM Better safe than sorry

Comment: So the answer to the exercise is "Should anybody want to try this with *three* slashes…”.

Comment: @GuM Bingo! :-)